# Send Time Optimization across business units

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, sfmc-einstein, einstein-sto

I have a lot of child business units handling marketing sends on country levels.
All of these child business units have Einstein STO turned on.
Some links in the mails sent on child business unit level have certain tracking aliases.
I monitor clicks on these tracking aliases, and if I notice a subscriber clicking on these links I send an email from the parent business unit to the subscriber exploring the content of the clicked link further.

I also have STO turned on on the parent business unit.
If the subscriber (always with a unique subscriber key) would have a assigned personal send time in the child business unit, would this subscriber also have an assigned personal send time in the parent business unit even though it might be the first time I'm targeting the subscriber from this business unit?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_anb_einstein_sto_model_details.htm&type=5#language-combobox):
"Einstein STO analyzes the past 90 days of email engagement history of all subscribers within the enterprise (top-level tenant in SFMC Email Studio)"

which related to my question above means Einstein analyzes email engagement for every subscriber across all business units, parent as well as child bu's.